# GridView Pagination Altering URL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview, url-rewriting

I'm using a GridView to display a set of records (cars) from my MSSQL DB. I am also using a URL rewrite on the same page.

The actual name of the page, including the query string, would be **Range.aspx?name=a1**, which is rewritten to **site.com/range/a1/**

The issue I'm having is that when I try to page through the records in the GridView, the URL changes to **site.com/range/a1/?name=a1**, which breaks the URL rewrite and in turn makes the GridView think there's no data to display.

Here's the URL rewrite I'm using in my Web.Config file:

```
<rule name="rwRangeResults" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^range/([^/]+)/?$"/>
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/Range.aspx?name={R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

I'm unsure if this is something I've got wrong with the rewrite, or whether I need to do something with the GridView to prevent it changing the URL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Really hoping someone can help me with this??

Comment: Jimmy, did you ever find a solution to this issue? Can you share the solution please.

Comment: Sorry, I never got his figured out :( The project was archived a while ago in favour of a WordPress platform.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks for responding.